# How to pass associative array to javascript

Tags: php, jquery

I've got the following associative array (`$the_array`):

```
Array
(
    [NAME 1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [transaction_id] => 6235944829
                [transaction_date] => 30/06/2017
                [transaction_description] => ALDI STORES        S
                [transaction_amount] => 7
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [transaction_id] => 6229871969
                [transaction_date] => 29/06/2017
                [transaction_description] => CRUTHERLAND HOUSE
                [transaction_amount] => 126
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [transaction_id] => 6229871971
                [transaction_date] => 29/06/2017
                [transaction_description] => MARKS&SPENCER PLC SACA
                [transaction_amount] => 6.7
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [transaction_id] => 6229871975
                [transaction_date] => 29/06/2017
                [transaction_description] => HARRY RAMSDEN
                [transaction_amount] => 10.43
            )

    )

    [NAME 2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [transaction_id] => 6203714807
                [transaction_date] => 21/06/2017
                [transaction_description] => MIDLAND HOTEL
                [transaction_amount] => 122.1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [transaction_id] => 6174035505
                [transaction_date] => 14/06/2017
                [transaction_description] => VIRGINTRAINSEC SERVCS
                [transaction_amount] => 117
            )

    )
)
```

How can I pass it to jQuery? This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't work:

on server side:

```
 echo json_encode((object) [
                        'uploaded' => true,
                        'message' => "test",
                        'match' => false,
                        'ac_array' => $the_array,
                        'ac_array_count' => $count_not_matched
                 ]);
```

on client side:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(result.ac_array);
```

Comment: What do you have on the server-side exactly? Note that you need script tags and you need to assign the result of `json_encode()` to a javascript variable. And you don't need to cast to an object.

Comment: So what is `result.ac_array`? You have not shown us anywhere where that object is created or the property is set.

Answer (score 0):

on server side try

```
echo json_encode(array(
   'uploaded' => true,
   'message' => "test",
   'match' => false,
   'ac_array' => $the_array,
   'ac_array_count' => $count_not_matched
));
```

and

on client side try

```
var arr = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
```